# 2 calls to iframed colorbox on same page - only 1 working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I have a page where I want a text link AND an image link to open up
the same iframed page, however only the first link (p) is working. The
image link does open up the colorbox and displays the title as it
should, but just doesn't display the content of the iframe - it's completely blank.

```
$("body.mediaPackPage p.genericLinkButton a,
body.mediaPackPage .rightImageColumn a img").colorbox({width:"90%",
height:"90%", iframe: true, title: "Online Media
Pack"});

    <p class="genericLinkButton"><a href="media_pack/index.html">Online Media Pack magazine <span class="smallArrow">></span></a></p>
 <div class="rightImageColumn"><a href="media_pack/index.html"><img src="/img_middleColumn/media-pack.jpg" alt="Media Pack" /></a></div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What if you assign this to the anchor, not the image? meaning `body.mediaPackPage .rightImageColumn a` instead of `body.mediaPackPage .rightImageColumn a img`

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Just out of interest, why do you think it still fired the colorbox when the function was assigned to the img? I'm still new to jQuery you see...

Comment: Cheers, not sure why - see my answer for best guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning this to the anchor, not the image:

```
$("body.mediaPackPage p.genericLinkButton a, body.mediaPackPage .rightImageColumn a").colorbox(...);
```

By assigning this to  the image, two click events happen - first is for the image second is for the link so maybe it's "toggling" something behind the scenes.

You can also solve this by having `return false` to cancel any further click events, but in your case better to handle only one event to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML, there's a double '>' somewhere which might cause troubles..

Comment: Hi - do you mean the '>' within the <span>?I did remove this completely and it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: This is the HTML parser of SO parsing `&gt;` as `>`